# User: anonymous is not authorized" to perform es:ESHttpGet

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-ec2

I setup elasticSearch domain with public domain access on EC2-classic and setup the access policy for with my ip. i  can access the kibana from web browser and the endpoint from the brower. when i try to test connection from private subnet  the es domain endpoint using the curl   am getting this error: `User: anonymous is not authorized" to perform es:ESHttpGet  erro`. Can someone please help?

Comment: Can you paste curl command you are using ?

Comment: @Ankam  Here is the command: curl -v -GET "https://vpc-teslardev-zophxfw6femer65mll6ozavt7m.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com:443/_cluster/health"

Comment: It is not easy to provide a solution without checking access policy and all, see if this helps https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/anonymous-not-authorized-elasticsearch/,  this says that even syntax issue in access policy returns that error